# Mixed surrogate composite key insert in JPA 2.0, PostgreSQL and Hibernate 3.5

Tags: java, jpa, sequence, composite-key, surrogate-key

First off, we are using JPA 2.0 and Hibernate 3.5 as persistence provider on a PostgreSQL database.

We successfully use the sequence of the database via the JPA 2.0 annotations as an auto-generated value for single-field-surrogate-keys and all works fine.

Now we are implementing a bi-temporal database-scheme that requires a mixed key in the following manner:

```
Table 1:
id             (pk, integer, auto-generated-sequence)
validTimeBegin (pk, dateTime)
validTimeEnd   (dateTime)
firstName      (varChar)
```

Now we have a problem. You see, if we `INSERT` a new element, the field `id` is auto-generated and that's fine. Only, if we want to `UPDATE` the field within this scheme, then we have to change the `validTimeBegin` column WITHOUT changing the `id`-field and insert it as a new row like so:

BEFORE THE UPDATE OF THE ROW:

```
|---|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------|
| id|      validTimeBegin     |       validTimeEnd      |     firstName     |
|---|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------|
|  1| 2010-05-01-10:00:00.000 |                    NULL |            Gerald |
|---|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------|
```

AFTER THE UPDATE OF THE ROW happening at exactly 2010-05-01-10:35:01.788 server-time:

```
(we update the person with the id:1 to reflect his new first name...)
|---|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------|
| id|      validTimeBegin     |       validTimeEnd      |     firstName     |
|---|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------|
|  1| 2010-05-01-10:00:00.000 | 2010-05-01-10:35:01.788 |            Gerald |
|---|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------|
|  1| 2010-05-01-10:35:01.788 |                    NULL |             Jerry |
|---|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------|
```

So our problem is, that this doesn't work at all using an auto-generated-sequence for the field `id` because when inserting a new row then the id ALWAYS is auto-generated although it really is part of a composite key which should sometimes behave differently.

So my question is:
Is there a way to tell hibernate via JPA to stop auto-generating the `id`-field in the case I want to generate a new variety of the same person and go on as usual in every other case or do I have to take over the whole id-generation with custom code?

Thanks in advance,
Gerald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... Some time has passed now without any comments and now I'm pretty sure that there's no way to do that. In fact it's one of the reasons why developers start generating their own unique keys for databases via their own id-generators on the application-side.
This way the database never even knows about such a thing as a surrogate key; It just receives it.

By the way:
We solved our problem by implementing our own methods for the task of updating such rows. These methods now are OR-Mapper dependent and in no way JPA 2.0 compliant but JPA just doesn't support an annotation for such behavior.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK your ID field is not an ID in the sense as Hibernate understands it. If I might propose another solution, given the fact that essentially you just want to realize database modification logging:

- Step 0: Only use ID as a primary key in Hibernate. Use a compound primary key in Postgres.
- Step 1: Add filters to hibernate that automatically filter all rows having validEndTime set.
- Step 2: Add custom update statement to hibernate, that does an insert instead.
- Step 3: Add trigger in PostgreSQL that sets the end time automatically.
- Step 4: Create a constrained index on postgres for faster lookups by hibernate.

Comment: First off, thanks for the answer.
It's a completely different approach to the problem.
However, we are bound to use JPA2.0 and there is no filter-construct that i could find, I dislike database-triggers as they are code I have to maintain that is not within my IDE and not telling hibernate that I have a compound key doesn't solve the problem of the generated id which was what the question was all about, really.
Nevertheless this approach you discribed, technically, is completely valid and OK with me. I just don't see how this solves the problem.